# Issues using pip install on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I've just installed Python 2.7 and I want to install the module "Pyomo". I checked to install Pip when I installed Python. Hence I open the command window in the folder where I have Python installed and write:

```
 pip install pyomo
```

which gives me a

```
 Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after Connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03075190>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. <connect timeout=15)')': \simple\pip
```

When I tried to google this issue I found that pip is trying to update itself by default when using it for the first time, and that disabling this will solve the problem. Hence I tried:

```
 pip install pyomo --disable-pip-version-check
```

With the same results, and after googling some more I tried:

```
 python -m pip install pyomo (with and without the extension) --disable-pip-version-check
```

Where both these practices gave me the same problem with Retrying.

I also tried to update Pip myself using:

```
 python -m pip Install -U pip
```

With the same result.

I tried to use

```
 python get-pip.py
```

as well Before this, but this gave me an error "Can't open file get-pip.py, no such file or directory. Lastly I found a python file for get-pip.py which I copied into that folder and then used **python get-pip.py** again, but now it gave the same Retry as the other attempts.

I have Internet connection, and I used the option regarding Path in the installation. Does anybody have any clue what is causing this issue? I have Another version of python installed, can this cause the problem? I don't have any folder or anything named Pip but I got 3 pip files in the Scripts folder, pip, pip2.7 and pip2 - have I missed any step?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Connection timeouts have been known to be caused by firewall issues. It is at least worth checking. out.

Comment: @MartinEvans Thansk for your reply! I will definitely check into that!